# While reader.read loop inside while reader2.read loop?

Tags: sql, vb.net

how can i do a while reader.read loop inside while reader2.read loop? here is my code:

```
While reader2.Read

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    a = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID='" & reader2("ID") & "'"
    sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(a, dbcon)
    reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read
        MsgBox(reader("FNAME"))
    End While

End While
```

Is that possible? i tried it but says i need to close the reader first. i am thinking that maybe it is possible if i store reader2 values in an array but i don't know how to do it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid DBMS calls inside loops because they are very expensive. They cause a lot of network roundtrips and slows down the sequential execution of your program.

You can store the IDs from first query into an array as follows

```
Dim IDs_list As New List(Of Integer)
While reader2.Read
IDs_list.Add(reader2("ID"))
End While
```

Once you have all the ids you can all people's data in single query using SQL [in](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) statement. You can join all ids using following code

```
String.Join(",", list.ToArray)
```

After that just run the query and get your results with your above code as follows

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    a = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID in (" & String.Join(",", list.ToArray) & ")"
    sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(a, dbcon)
    reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        MsgBox(reader("FNAME"))
    End While
```

Comment: I didn't ran this code in IDE, so Kindly fix any typo syntax error yourself.

Comment: can we use the result in a for each loop? because each result ids have multiple values in a table.

Comment: on second query from people?, Yes you can loop over those as well

Comment: can you teach me @Haseeb Asif on how to use it in for each loop?

Comment: yeah sure, It's the same way as we do a while loop. Have you tried something so far?